# C# Linq query as a function parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq to get some data from my database. When query is empty I want to throw an exception.

```
public class LinqDataBaseConnector : IDataBaseConnector
{
    public LinqDatabaseDataContext dataContext;

    public User getUser(string login, string password)
    {
        var query = (from c in dataContext.Users
                     where c.username == login && c.password == password
                     select c);

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return query.First();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Empty query!");
        }
    }

    public HardwareConfiguration getHardwareConfiguration(int id)
    {
        var query = (from c in dataContext.HardwareConfigurations
                     where c.ID == id
                     select c);

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return query.First();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Empty query!");
        }
    }
}
```

How to extract this if/else to ONE private method. Do I need to implement `IQueryable<T>` interface ?

Comment: The code, as you currently have it, is executing the query twice; one to see if it has any items, and once to actually get the first time.  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Do not throw `NullReferenceException` instead throw `InvalidArgumentException`

Comment: `query.First()` will _already_ throw an exception if the query is empty - why not just use that?

Comment: Additionally, uif you expect one and only one result, use `Single()` rather than `First()`

Comment: I want to return onlt first element from query when it is not empty. Exception should be thrown when it is empty

Comment: @rungus2 Which is *exactly* the behavior of `First`.

Answer (score 8):

Don't call `Any`, just call `First`.  It will throw an exception if the query has no items, which is exactly what you want.  There's no need to create another operator as `First` already has the appropriate semantics.

In addition to just being easier, it results in the database query being executed just once, rather than twice.

Comment: Seems to be fine now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simplified code below. Also i do hope you have some password hashing and not just plain text.

```
public class LinqDataBaseConnector : IDataBaseConnector
{
    #region Private Variables
    public LinqDatabaseDataContext dataContext;
    #endregion

    public User getUser(string login, string password)
    {   
        return this.dataContext.Users.First(x => x.username == login && x.password == password);
    }

    public HardwareConfiguration getHardwareConfiguration(int id)
    {   
        return this.dataContext.HardwareConfigurations.First(x => x.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
    var query = (from c in dataContext.Users
                 where c.username == login && c.password == password
                 select c).FirstOrDefault();

    if (query!=null)
    {
        return query;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Empty query!");
    }
```

Comment: As stated above no reason to throw an exception since First will throw if there is no results to the query its adding extra code the framework will already do.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you cannot implement it as an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetFirstOrException<T>(this IEnumerable<T> myList)
    {
        if (myList.Any())
        {
            return myList.First();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Empty query!");
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases you can then use the extension method:

```
public User getUser(string login, string password)
{
    var query = (from c in dataContext.Users
                 where c.username == login && c.password == password
                 select c);

    return query.GetFirstOrException();
}

public HardwareConfiguration getHardwareConfiguration(int id)
{
    var query = (from c in dataContext.HardwareConfigurations
                 where c.ID == id
                 select c);

    return query.GetFirstOrException();
}
```